# Can't seem to move folders over with wild cards using PSCP from DOS to Linux?

Tags: linux, dos, pscp

The path has spaces in the folder names, so I am using wildcards: "*" to move the 5 folders within it to Linux using PSCP.

```
pscp C:\Public\SMoch\hot*testing*8*20*13\. chad@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:.

pscp C:\Public\SMoch\hot testing 8 20 13: No such file or directory
```

I am able to cd to it in DOS: `cd C:\Public\SMoch\hot*testing*8*20*13\`  ... works

Not sure what I am doing wrong with pscp?

Answer (score 1):

Try using double quotes when working with paths in Windows. "C:\There are spaces in this path" when

Comment: when i try:  pscp "C:\Public\SMoch\hot testing 8 20 13\*" chad@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:.   yields results of "not a regular file".  However if I replace the spaces with "_" it all works fine.